# Why do my versions not come up?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I don't know what happened but, I was playing Minecraft and everything was working perfectly. Next day I get on and it made me redownload the game. And all my versions are gone! All my versions are in my versions folder, but when I open my Minecraft launcher and go into "Use Version" nothing is in there?! Please help!

Also, If this is helpful, all my resourcepacks work great. It's just my versions that don't work.

(One last thing, it's only my mod versions. Like Optifine, and Forge.)

Comment: "It's only my mod versions" -> question is off topic as tech support for modded minecraft.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is asking about modded mc support

Answer (score 2):

Redownloading the launcher will cause this problem. There is a .json file in the .minecraft directory that saves all that information. It has most likely been erased so there is no way to retrieve it but by re-running the installers for optifine and forge will fix your issue.

Comment: Redownloading the _launcher_? You mean game version?

Comment: When the minecraft launcher is downloaded it creates launcher files in the .minecraft directory. One of the files stores all the minecraft versions. When the launcher is reinstalled it overwrites these files resulting in the missing mod versions.

Comment: I don't think so. I'm not seeing anything that suggests that. I think it gets the list from the mojang servers. Otherwise could you say which file it is?

Comment: The file is named versions.json and is retrieved from http://s3.amazonaws.com/Minecraft.Download/versions/versions.json when it is downloaded it overwrites the current file in the directory

Comment: Which folder is it in? I still don't see anything

Comment: The launcher downloads the .json file and launcher generates folders in the /versions directory inside of every directory it has a json file and a jar file that the launcher executes to run the game. By redownloading the launcher it should delete all the version folders and everytime you run a new game it will replace them with the new folders that it gets from versions.json

Comment: Oh, I get you now. And it's inefficient to redownload the files everytime. They should just check to hash and redownload if needed

Comment: I agree. Glad to have helped.

Answer (score 0):

On the latest launcher, going to `Installations` > `(+) New` > `Version`, I was able to find the mods I installed, despite them not appearing under my profiles before.